# Highlight columns which differer from previous lines

Tags: regex, vim, syntax-highlighting

I have text file with numerical data written in lines; there are interspersed input lines (unknowns) and residuals lines (which are supposed to be minimized). I am investigating ways how the iterative solver handles various cases, and would like to highlight every  (space-delimited) field in the residuals line which is (textually) different from the same field in the previous residuals line (2 lines above, better given by a regexp). I am free to decorate beginnings of the lines as I like, if that helps.

Is this at all possible with Vim and some regexp magic?

Example file:

```
input 1 2 3 4 5 6
errors .2 .2 .3 .1 0 0
input 1 2.1 2.9 4 5 6    ## here, 2.1 and 2.9 should be highlighted
errors .21 .3 .44 .3 0 0
input 1 2 3 3.9 5.2 6    ## here, 2, 3, 3.9 and 5.2 should be highlighted
errors .2 .2 .34 .9 1 0
```

Note: I could code script extracting differences in Python, but I want to have a look at both the actual data and the changes. When it does not work with Vim, I will process it with python and output highlighted HTML, but I will lose automatic folding capabilities.